# How to replace the default success handler with a custom handler from a Grails login form?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a situation where I need to replace the default success handler with a custom one in Grails using Spring.

The default handler is defined in AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter as a SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler - I need to replace this with my custom success handler. I noticed there is a setAuthenticationSuccessHandler() method in that class.

How do I use that method to set it to my custom one?

In resources.groovy I have my custom success handler defined:

```
authenticationSuccessHandler (CustomUserLoginSuccessHandler) {
    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    requestCache = ref('requestCache')
    redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
    defaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
    alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault
    targetUrlParameter = conf.successHandler.targetUrlParameter
    ajaxSuccessUrl = conf.successHandler.ajaxSuccessUrl
    useReferer = conf.successHandler.useReferer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my security config (`@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity`), I have a bean defining a success handler (which presumably you could swap for your resources-defined one):

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler(){
  return new ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationHandler()
}
```

I then add it to my HttpSecurity like

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    // other stuff cut out to make this shorter
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .successHandler(successHandler())
}
```